# Should I compile the linux kernel in the git repository itself?

Tags: git, linux-kernel, build

This is about common practices. I have a git repository containing the linux kernel. Now I want to build this linux kernel. Should I copy the sources outside the git repository and then build the kernel ? Or, should I run the build inside the git repository itself? My concern is about the many files that are created during a build process that should, I think, be not included in the git repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's okay to compile in the repository itself. New files are ignored by Git until you add them manually for the first time. (You can use `make mrproper` or `git clean -dfx` to get rid of compilation output.)

Comment: can't I do a make clean ? is that the same as make mrproper ?

Comment: @AnkurVj: `make clean` usually cleans just the compilation output (object files). `make distclean` removes everything that shouldn't be included in published tarballs of the source code. `make mrproper` is specific to Linux source and is something in-between: more aggressive than `make clean` but less so than `make distclean`. See [Makefile lines 1148 and below](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;h=788511f86a6233ff6a24a4704a556dd4a7fba14f;hb=HEAD#l1148).